# How to fix 403 issue using WebQuest,WebClient & httpclient c# webapi while scrapping data from third party Application

Tags: .net

How to  fix 403 issue using Web Request, Web Client  & HTTP client c# webapi while scrapping data from third party Application.

I am trying to create api end point using web request get method, web client post method for third applications api's